# How do I prevent Visual Studio from opening tabs during debug stepping?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

Ok this is driving me nuts now.  I used to be able to step debug (F11) in Visual Studio and it would only preview the code file rather than opening it in a tab.  Now during debug, as VS is jumping to different code files and methods, it opens the items in the tab well and leaves them open.  I could have sworn there was a setting for this.  I'm just not seeing it.  It started happening 5-6 months ago and I keep scanning settings for it and come up blank every time.

Comment: I can't help you with your issue, but this has always been the behavior for me. I've never seen this "preview the code file" behavior

Comment: hmmmm.  Perhaps it was an extension that I had installed in the past.  I will look into that.  It was incredibly helpful in keeping my tab-well clean.

Comment: Looks like a bug in VS. See https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/155983/debuggingpreview-tab-feature-broken-in-155-preview.html

Comment: @SergeyVlasov Thank you for the link!  It's still not working in VS 15.7.3, so I bumped the request.